# Ninject Get<T> with constructor argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ninject, inversion-of-control

Here is my Module:

```
public class LoggerModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogLogger>()
            .WithConstructorArgument(
                typeof(Type),
                x => x.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type);
    }
}
```

So as you can see the `NLogLogger` is expecting the `Type` to be passed into the constructor.

This is my Unit Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void ResolveLoggerDependency()
    {
        var module = new LoggerModule();
        var kernal = new StandardKernel(module);
        var service = kernal.Get<ILogger>(new ConstructorArgument("type", typeof(int)));
        Assert.That(service, Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

It is throwing a null reference error on the `kernal.Get<ILogger>` so I can only assume I am not passing the constructor value correctly. How can I pass in a `Type` when using `Get<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this question as it seems relates to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790832/ninject-pass-constructor-argument-typeof-class-that-implements-the-interface).

The requirement in that question was to inject into `NLogLogger` the type of the object into which the it will be injected.

The registration in this case is assuming that this interface `ILogger` will not be resolved outside the context of a parent class into which it will be injected. And you are getting the exception because there is no parent class context when you directly attempt to resolve the `ILogger` interface.

I am assuming that in your unit test, your would like to test that this registration actually work. I would suggest the following:

First, create a class the you will use in your tests:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly ILogger m_Logger;

    public TestClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        m_Logger = logger;
    }

    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return m_Logger; }
    }
}
```

And then use such class in your unit tests like this:

```
[Test]
public void ResolveLoggerDependency()
{
    var module = new LoggerModule();
    var kernal = new StandardKernel(module);
    var test_object = kernal.Get<TestClass>();
    Assert.That(test_object.Logger, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

You can further verify that the `NLogLogger` actually used the `TestClass` class's name to construct the NLog logger. This might require the use of [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) though, I am not sure.

Comment: That helps a lot in my understanding of how `kernal.Get<T>` works. Thanks you (again).

Comment: @JamieR, please note that use of `Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type` created the requirement of having a parent object when resolving `ILogger`.

Answer (score -1):

In your Load method you can just set it up using `Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogLogger>();`

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question. My Binding is correct because NLogLogger has a constructor with a parameter. I'm having a problem trying to unit test it by using `Get<T>` I need to know how to pass a constructor argument to `Get<T>`

Comment: Here's as an example that I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310847/ninject-passing-constructor-argument-to-the-kernel

Comment: Nope, Still getting a null reference: `var service = kernal.Get<ILogger>(new Parameter("t", typeof(string), false));`